# When does $cov(X,Y)\neq 0$ imply $cov(XZ,ZY)\neq 0$?

Tags: random-variable, covariance

For random variables $X$,$Y$,$Z$, when does $cov(X,Y)\neq 0$ imply $cov(XZ,ZY)\neq 0$? It would be great if you could provide some sufficient conditions or give some special cases such that this hold.

Comment: Assume $\mathbb E[X]=0$ and $(X,Y)$ independent from $Z$. Then$$\text{cov}(XZ,YZ)=\mathbb E[ZXZY]=\mathbb E[Z^2XY]=\mathbb E[Z^2\mathbb E[XY|Z]]=\mathbb E[Z^2]\text{cov}(X,Y)$$

Comment: And to complement that observation by @Xi'an, given any $(X,Y),$ let $Z$ be the indicator of $(X,Y)=(0,0),$ so that $XZ=0=YZ$ always. In this way you can obtain many examples where $(X,Y)$ has nonzero covariance but $(XZ,YZ)$ has zero covariance.  The simplest possible example assigns nonzero probabilities to the two $(X,Y,Z)$ values $(0,0,1)$ and $(1,1,0)$ and zero probabilities to all other values.

Comment: @whuber I see. This is very insightful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you very much! This is very helpful!